# How to make a Drawable object with my selected color in code

Tags: android, swing, android-layout

I am trying to set icon of selected color to a preference:

```
Preference prf = (Preference) findPreference("SelectColorPref");
```

`prf.setIcon(Drawbale icon);`

For this i need an object `Drawable` of selected color.

Is this possible to make a `Drawable` icon in java code? Please guide me..

Regards,

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

After following Aleks G's concept it solved as:

```
Preference TextClrPref = (Preference) findPreference("text_color_preference");

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas cnv = new Canvas(bm); 
int red = 0xffff0000; 
cnv.drawColor(red); 
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm); 

TextClrPref .setIcon(drawable);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a solid-colour Drawable using code similar to this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas cnv = new Canvas(bm);
int red = 0xff0000;
cnv.drawColor(red);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
```

This will create a Drawable containing a 50x50 pixels red square.

(Please note that I haven't tested this code, but I use something similar in my code.)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way using **[ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html)**

```
 ShapeDrawable sdrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
 sdrawable.paint.Color = color.RED;
 sdrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(10);
 sdrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(40);
```