# How to create Drawables by code in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to create a simple blue Drawable by java code. I do not want to add a 'blue' image in res/drawable folder. How do I achieve this? I need to use this drawable in an ImageView as an image.

[image]

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033309/how-to-make-a-drawable-object-with-my-selected-color-in-code See if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html), which will let you set a Bitmap as the source. You can create bitmaps pretty easily using many functions such as:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
myBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLUE);
```

If you want a solid color, you can create a 1x1 bitmap with that pixel and scale it up as needed.

Alternatively, if you want more flexibility, you can use a [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) which lets you use more drawing methods (for rectangles, circles, text, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can define a ShapeDrawable in XML (yes I'm aware that you want to do it in code but maybe that would work for you as well):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="150dp"
        android:height="150dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000ff" />
</shape>
```

The XML makes support of multiple screens easy (screen resolutions, screen densities, form factors, orientation). More on how to define shapes can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

Comment: I tried it with ShapeDrawable through code and it worked with imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(). But this method has been deprecated in API 16. Moreover, shapeDrawable object did not work with imageView.setImageDrawable() method. So BitmapDrawable is the way to go. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myshape) works nicely though ;-)